# Get a dict of all properties of self without including child class properties

Tags: python

Say I have the following two classes:

```
class PlayerState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.someStateProp = 10

    # get the state of this class only as a dict
    def getState(self):
        return {name: attr for name, attr in self.__dict__.items()
                if not name.startswith("__")
                and not callable(attr)
                and not type(attr) is staticmethod}

class Player(PlayerState):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.someNonStateProp = 'foo'

player = Player()
print(player.getState())
# someNonStateProp should not be shown
>> {'someStateProp': 10, 'someNonStateProp': 'foo'}
```

The method `PlayerState.getState` as it stands is able to return a `dict` containing all attributes of itself, excluding constructors and methods. I want to expand on it and make it also only return the direct properties of `PlayerState`, and not `Player`.

Edit: Using `self.__class__.__dict__.items()` instead of `self.__dict__.items()` just gives me all the methods of `Player`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python get only class attribute no superclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241528/python-get-only-class-attribute-no-superclasses)

Comment: @FThompson Just tried that, using `self.__class__.__dict__.items()` instead of `self.__dict__.items()` just gives me all the methods of `Player`.

Comment: @FThompson. That's exactly the opposite of what OP is asking. They want superclass only.

Comment: Attributes belong to the instance (note, methods would not be in an instances dict). there is no inherent difference between methods added by a method that belongs to a superclass and those in the subclass - you'll have to keep track of this yourself.

Comment: You really don't need `and not type(attr) is staticmethod`, unless you imagine staticmethods aren't callables for some reason. If that were the case, you might want to start checking for classmethods as well, even though neither will appear in `__dict__`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist staticmethod objects aren't callable, actually, but you are right that it isn't necessary because a staticmethod should not end up as an instance attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide no way to really differentiate between state and non-state attributes. If the object is mutable and has a mutable dict, there is really no way to determine who set the value for a particular attribute. There will be cases where children will want to add to the state. If the state is something special, keep it as a separate dictionary instead of filtering every time:

```
class PlayerState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = {}
        self.state['someProp'] = 10

    # get the state of this class only as a dict
    def getState(self):
        return self.state

class Player(PlayerState):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.someNonStateProp = 'foo'
        self.state['otherProp'] = 'bar'
```

If it bothers you that you can't access state elements through normal dot access, add some properties to your class:

```
@property
def someStateProp(self):
    return self.state['someProp']
```

Alternatively, hard-code a list of the names you want.

```
class PlayerState:
    states = ['someStateProp']

    def __init__(self):
        self.someStateProp = 10

    # get the state of this class only as a dict
    def getState(self):
        return {name: getattr(self, name) for name in self.names}

class Player(PlayerState):
    names = PlayerState.names + ['otherStateProp']

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.someNonStateProp = 'foo'
```