# Why is '__dict__' not in Class.__dict__ for derived classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, derived-class, weak-references

Consider this:

```
class Base:
  pass

class Derived(Base):
  pass

print(Base.__dict__)
print(Derived.__dict__)

print('__dict__' in Base.__dict__)
print('__dict__' in Derived.__dict__)
```

The output is:

```
{'__module__': '__main__', '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Base' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Base' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
True
False
```

Why are the `'__dict__'` and `'__weakref__'` keys missing for the `Derived` class?
What does this mean/affect?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529929/python-class-inheritance-and-dict-lookup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python get only class attribute no superclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241528/python-get-only-class-attribute-no-superclasses)

Comment: Those are good references. I can't quite connect the dots though how that applies to `'__dict__'` specifically then, and not for example for `'__module__'` or `'__doc__'` and how the Python object model then works. Does it start in the most-subclassed `__dict__` and keeps going with the MRO until it finds the key its looking for in the successive `__dict__`'s?